# Angular IE11 returns CORS error but data still returns

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular 6 with RXJS. Making requests using `HttpClient` and `HttpParams` is returning the error `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.` Which, based on research, should be a CORS error on the server where I'm calling the api request. However, I still get data back and it displays. Additionally, I have another portion of the app that makes and API call to the same server but I don't get that error.